# Swift - Cannot pass codable parameters with different type

Tags: swift, codable

I'm having a problem to pass this Codable as parameter for my api service.

The **value** key has different types (String, Bool, Int). I always get **String** values of those whenever I pass this as my parameter :(

```
{   
    "deviceId": "aabbcc112233",
    "commands": [
        {
            "code": "mode",
            "value": "play"
        },
        {
            "code": "start",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "code": "timer",
            "value": 4
        }
    ],
    "type": "activity"
}
```

My current code is this:

```
struct MyParameter: Codable {
  var deviceId: String
  var commands: [CommandStatus]
  var type: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case deviceId = "deviceId"
    case commands = "commands"
    case type = "type"
  }
}


struct CommandStatus: Codable {
  var code: String
  var value: String
  
  init(code: String, value: String) {
    self.code = code
    self.value = value
  }
  init(code: String, value: Int) {
    self.code = code
    self.value = String(value)
  }
  init(code: String, value: Bool) {
    self.code = code
    self.value = String(value)
  }
  
  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(value, forKey: .value)
    try container.encode(value.boolValue, forKey: .value)
    try container.encode((value as NSString).integerValue, forKey: .value)
  }
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case code, value
  }
}
```

Can someone help me understand more on how to do this?

Comment: Just use JSONSerialization instead

Comment: You've defined value as a String, so I'm not clear why'll you are expecting it to be someting else?  Are you saying that when you encode your CommandStatus struct that you wish it to convert a numeric string back to its Int value and "true" or "false" back to the corresponding Boolean?

Comment: I'm at lost there, I don't know what type should I use since there are 3 type that needs to handle

Comment: By the way, I have fix it now using JSONSerialization. Thanks @LeoDabus for the idea